TexShop edit/statistics deals incorrectly with ‘ and ’
This is more of a problem report than a question. I would fix it myself if I knew how to access the TexShop code efficiently.
I am using MacTex 2024, TexShop 5.42 with up to date packages.
When I ran edit/statistics on a piece of tex zeroes result if ‘ or ’ are present. These are not to be confused with '. After a restart of TexShop ‘ and ’ are each counted as 3 characters.
Besides the DeTex documentation in TexLive states that Detex is 'retired' and OpenDeTex should be used.
Package: detex
Summary: Strip TeX from a source file
Status: Installed
Description:
Detex is a program to remove TeX constructs from a text file. It recognizes the \input command. The program assumes it is dealing with LaTeX input if it sees the string \begin{document} in the text. In this case, it also recognizes the \include and \includeonly commands. The author now considers this program to be "retired" and Piotr Kubowicz's OpenDetex as its successor.

You can probably use https://github.com/TeXShop/TeXShop  (which says it's unoffical but it's linked from the main page at https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/obtaining.html
